# Kendo Grid Destroy Command Not Refreshing Grid

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In below grid i have implemented Destroy method to delete records, but the issue is when an error occurred during deletion on server side, kendo grid still remove the record from grid. when i refresh the page record appears again as expected. how can i prevent kendo grid from removing a record if server side error occurred and show a error message to user?

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<RealEstateApp.Models.propertyOwenerModel>)Model)
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.id).Visible(false);

            columns.Bound(o => o.name).Width("150px");
            columns.Bound(o => o.email).Width("100px");
            columns.Bound(o => o.address).Width("200px");
            columns.Bound(o => o.telephone).Width("100px");
            columns.Bound(o => o.mobile).Width("100px");

            columns.Template(o => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { o.id })).ClientTemplate("<a class='k-button k-button-icontext' href=\"" + Url.Action("Edit", "propertyOwner") + "/#= id#\"><span class='k-icon k-edit'></span>Edit</a>").Width(80).Title("Edit");
            if (Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "admin"))
            {
                columns.Command(commands =>
                {

                        commands.Destroy(); // The "destroy" command removes data items


                }).Title("Delete").Width(90);
            }
            //columns.Template(o => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { o.id })).ClientTemplate("<a class='blue' href=\"" + Url.Action("Details", "propertyOwner") + "/#= id#\"><i class='icon-zoom-in bigger-130'>Delete</i></a>").Width(65).Title("Details");
        })
        .ToolBar(toolbar =>
        {

            toolbar.Template(@<text>
    <a class="k-button" href="/propertyOwner/Create"><span class="k-icon k-si-plus"></span></a>
    </text>);


        })
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable()
        .Filterable()
        .Groupable()
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:900px;" })

         .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(20)
            .Read(read => read.Action("AjaxGrid", "propertyOwner"))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Destroy", "propertyOwner"))

                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(m=>m.id); // Specify the property which is the unique identifier of the model
                    model.Field(m => m.id).Editable(false); // Make the ProductID property not editable
                })
                 )


    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define an [`errors`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.errors) function or field in you `Schema` definition, this is the field where your server sends the notification to the UI.

Then, in the `DataSource` define an [`error`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#events-error) event handler that displays the alert message (or whatever you want to do).

Example of a DataSource definition using `errors` field definition and `error` event handler:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/twitter/search",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: { q: "#" }
        }
    },
    schema: {
        errors: "error" // twitter's response is { "error": "Invalid query" }
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.errors); // displays "Invalid query"
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** If you need to do some complex validation and not just saying which field contains the error, you might define an `errors` function in you `schema` that returns `true` for error and `false` for ok!.

Example:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/twitter/search",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: { q: "#" }
        }
    },
    schema: {
        errors: function (d) {
            // twitter's response is { "error": "Invalid query" }
            return (d.error && d.error !== "ok") ? true : false;
        }
    },
    error: function(e) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: now i can display an error, but still the record is removed from the grid and it's not refreshing

Comment: For not getting it removed, you should define an `errors` function that return `true`, when there is no `error`, your function should return `false`. See my **EDIT** to the question.